# Why is my output for Balanced Bracket Problem using Recursion wrong

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

So I wrote some recursive code for printing balanced brackets when number of bracket pairs (noOfPairs) are given as the input. But my answers are wrong.

For example: On inputting n = 2, the two types of brackets would be (()) or ()() but my program is outputting (()) and (()( which is wrong. Kindly help!

```
// Generate Brackets Strings Problem
// Using Recursion
// Given a number N, generate BALANCED BRACKETS using n pairs of Round Brackets

#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

// recursive function
void generateBrackets(string output, int noOfPairs, int open, int close) {   // open = open brac ; close = close brac
    // base case
    if (output.length() == 2 * noOfPairs) {
        cout << output << endl;
        return;
    }
    // adding brackets (recursive)
    // 2 ways in the middle of the string
    if (open < noOfPairs) {
        output.push_back('(');
        generateBrackets(output, noOfPairs, open + 1, close);
    }
    if (close < open) {
        output.push_back(')');
        generateBrackets(output, noOfPairs, open, close + 1);
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    // input
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of pairs of round brackets" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    // make an output string
    string output;

    generateBrackets(output, n, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was literally *born* to send into a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) for single-stepping, especially since you have a trivially reproducible case.

Comment: i did that, and the problem is with the number of times the return statement is working! After this -- (()) is printed, the return statement should work 3 times to remove the last 3 brackets thus leaving the output string as -- ( but the return statement works just 2 times.

Comment: @DivijJain *"the return statement should work 3 times to remove the last 3 brackets"* -- The `return` statement does not remove anything. Try stepping through your code instead of just counting `return` statements. Pay attention to what happens immediately *after* returning.

Comment: You need to pop the bracket you pushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first recursive call to `generateBrackets`, you need to pop the '(' that you had just pushed, because otherwise it will interfere with the next call where you add a close bracket.

Comment: Yeah i figured that out a couple of hours ago but i still don't understand why? Please help me solve this problem. I'm stuck for hours!

Comment: It's because the way your algorithm is supposed to work is that at each step, you try both options for what you could add - if you can add a "(" then try that, and if you can add a ")" then also try that. Because you're not popping the "(" in between, you're actually adding "(" and "()", instead of "(" and ")".

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void parenthesis(int open, int close, string brak)
{
   if (open == 0 && close == 0)
      cout<<brak;
   if (open>close)
      return;
   if (open > 0)
      parenthesis(open-1, close,brak + "(");
   if (close > 0)
      parenthesis(open, close - 1,brak + ")");
}
void printPar(int n)
{
   parenthesis(n,n,"\n");
}
int main()
{
   int n=1;
   printPar(n);
   return  0;

}
```

Comment: Slight explanation to your answers would be good